# How to solve django with mysql error in inserting

Tags: python, mysql, django

I create models for MySQL the foreign key
constraints always returning error

[image]

The model is

```
class AirPort(models.Model):

  code = models.CharField(max_length=3)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=100)

  def __str__(self):
     return f"{self.id} - CODE =>{self.code} :: CITY=> {self.city}"

class Flight(models.Model):

  orgin_id = models.ForeignKey(AirPort,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="dep")
  dest_id = models.ForeignKey(AirPort,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name="arrival")
  duration = models.IntegerField()

  def __str__(self):
      return f"{self.id} - {self.orgin} TO {self.dest} will take {self.duration} minutes"
```

and the shell output is

> a=Flight(orgin_id=1,dest_id=2,duration=120)
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "", line 1, in 
>     File "/home/kid/PycharmProjects/hardward/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 467, in **init**
>       _setattr(self, field.name, rel_obj)
>     File "/home/kid/PycharmProjects/hardward/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py", line 210, in **set**
>       self.field.remote_field.model._meta.object_name,
>   ValueError: Cannot assign "1": "Flight.orgin_id" must be a "AirPort" instance.

Comment: add your insert queryset

Comment: Don't call your FK `origin_id`, call it `origin`. Then you *can* use `origin_id` to assign via PK rather than instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try this

```
flight_result=Flight()
flight_result.orgin_id = AirPort.object.first()
flight_result.dest_id = AirPort.object.last()
flight_result.duration = 1000
flight_result.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
a=Flight(orgin=AirPort.object.get(id=1),dest=AirPort.object.get(id=2),duration=120)
```

Comment: thanks its worked but i cant save the error is 
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'orgin_id_id' in 'field list'")
this column is auto generated i dont know the reason 
please help

Comment: thank you its worked 
please explain does we need to run a=Flight(orgin=AirPort.object.get(id=1),dest=AirPort.object.get(id=2),duration=120)
this code instead of normal one in mysql for foreign key constraints

Answer (score 0):

Have you run python manage.py makemigrations...and migrated the data with python manage.py migrate

Comment: yes   django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'hello_flight.orgin_id_id' in 'field list'")

this is the problem every time i make migration it adds coloums like 
orgin_id_id and dest_id_id

Comment: Delete all the migrations in the migrations folder and then make migrations again.

Answer (score 0):

I received this error because I did not see the comma at the end

```
order.employee=Employee.objects.get(employee_id=x),
```

Its origin was that I used Order.objects.create() before, for which one uses comma separated attribute assignments and I did not immediately delete the commas. May it help someone who also sat too long in front of the computer :)